# Client WebService Authentication Without System.setProperty(Path Certificate)

Tags: java, certificate, webservice-client

I have a desktop application who access webservice with mutual authentication. The authentication uses System.setProperty and it works.

But I have to create physical file from my certificate and sometimes users change permissions in program's folder and also, is not safe to create physical file. I'm using an A1 certificate.

Is there way to access the webservice putting the certificate in memory or something like this?